# how to launch a batch file from a winform control

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file

I wrote a simple batch file to clear cache in a remote server. I want to be able to perform the task by logging in to the remote server with user name and the server location. So i developed a winform that will enable me to perfom this task i.e on button click, run the batch file. If there is no connection with the server, report that to a log file which is included in the batch file (RGB_CLEAR_APPV_LCACHE.002.bat >> AppVCache1_%date:/=%.log)

my problem is that, i cannot pass the username and and location from winform to the batch file. I have tried all I could but to no avail. the c# code and the batch file code is below. I am not sure if the problem is coming from the batch file or the c# code.

Any alternative and or suggestion that will help to get the code to work will be appreciated.

**c# code**

```
public partial class AppVForm : Form
{
    public AppVForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var file2 = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Files\cleaner2.bat");
            var file = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Files\RGB_CLEAR_APPV_LCACHE.002.bat");
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            text = text.Replace("##USERNAME##", userNameTexBox.Text);
            text = text.Replace("##LOCATION##", userLocationTextbox.Text);
            File.WriteAllText(file2, text);

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = file2;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AppVForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void userNameTexBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        bool cancel = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.userNameTexBox.Text))
        {
            cancel = true;
            errorProvider1.SetError(this.userNameTexBox, "You must provide a username.");
        }
        e.Cancel = cancel;
    }

    private void userNameTexBox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(userNameTexBox, string.Empty);
    } 
    private void userLocationTextbox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        bool cancel = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.userLocationTextbox.Text))
        {
            cancel = true;
            errorProvider1.SetError(this.userLocationTextbox, "You must provide a valid location.");
        }
        e.Cancel = cancel;
    }

    private void userLocationTextbox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(userLocationTextbox, string.Empty);
    }   
}
```

**batch file code**

```
::---------------------DECLARE STUFF HERE---------------------------
::----  Leave Colons and speech marks in place, the guts get messy without them!!--------
::----  LOC is the location of the machines C drive... If over network, use "\\COMPNAME\c$\ - With speech mark.  If locally, use "C:\  - With Speech Mark----------

set USERNAME_IS=##USERNAME##
set LOC="##LOCATION##

set H_1="\\greenwich\users\Home\
set h_2=\AppData\Roaming\SoftGrid Client\

set c_1=%##LOCATION##%users\
set c_2=\appdata\local\softgrid client\*.*?"

SET "STR1=%H_1%%##USERNAME##%%H_2%"

SET "STR2=%c_1%%##USERNAME##%%c_2%"

::---------------------Remove Files from H DRIVE ---------------------

move /y %STR1%shortcut_ex.dat %STR1%Icon Cache"
move /y ::%STR1%userinfo.dat" %STR1%Icon Cache"

ATTRIB +H %STR1%Icon Cache"
FOR /D %%i IN (%STR1%*") DO RD /S /Q "%%i" DEL /Q %STR1%*.*"
ATTRIB -H %STR1%Icon Cache"

move /y %STR1%Icon Cache\shortcut_ex.dat" %STR1%"
move /y %STR1%Icon Cache\userinfor.dat" %STR1%

::---------------------Remove Files from C DRIVE APPFS---------------------

del %##LOCATION##%ProgramData\Microsoft\Application Virtualization Client\SoftGrid Client\AppFS Storage\*.*?"

::---------------------:Remove Files from C Drive SOFTGRID---------------------

del %STR2%

@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO failLabel

:successLabel
ECHO Success
GOTO endLabel

:failLabel

@ECHO Clean up Failed
:endLabel

pause

RGB_CLEAR_APPV_LCACHE.002.bat >> AppVCache1_%date:/=%.log
pause
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pass arguments to a command line executable?

Comment: That might probably be the question. But in clear terms when the user enters the name and location of the server, the batch command should run. If it fails, then it should be reported in txt report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass them to the batch file using the arguments property ie:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = userNameTexBox.Text + " " + userLocationTextbox.Text
```

... and then, inside the batch file, read in the parameters like this:

```
set USERNAME_IS=%1
set LOC=%2
```

Comment: the code worked fine with your advice thanks. The problem I am faced with is now how to print out a log report after the batch file is ran. I used RGB_CLEAR_APPV_LCACHE.002.bat >> AppVCache1_%date:/=%.log but it does not produce any output in the solution file folder. It does fire an event log in the debug folder but completely empty. But when I double click on it, in the file folder,it fires up and produce a log file on the same folder.I want it to produce a log report on the solution file when the button click event is fired. Or is there a better way to get the log file from a batch process?